# How to remove tick lines from secondary y axis in highcharts heatmap graph

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

[image]I have manipulated highcharts heatmap graph to suit some of my requirement. But I am not able to hide the tick lines on secondary y axis. Below is the jsfiddle link of what I have done. http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepkparashar/39xBU/389/`389`
Please suggest how to hide the tick lines.

Comment: Is it the correct jsfiddle? I cannot see any ticks or the secondary y axis.

Comment: On the right vertical edge of the rectangular graph in the fiddle, you can see very minute tick lines. I have just attached a screenshot for more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, those lines are grid lines and an axis line (the one in the bottom). You can disable them by setting their width to 0.

```
xAxis: {
 lineWidth: 0 
 ...
},

yAxis: {
 gridLineWidth: 0,
 ...
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/sebdom/39xBU/390/